# XAML Override Control Library Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF custom controls library which is shared between multiple applications. In the library I have a resource dictionary which defines all the colours used by the custom controls.

However I'd like to have a separate resource dictionary in each application project which defines the colours specific to that application and can also override the library colour values, similar to the way system colour resources can be overrided.

I know I could maintain separate styles for each application, but that would mean exposing every colour which needs to be changed as a property, which seems pointless and against the WPF model of only exposing Foreground, Background, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually worked it out.

I created a resource dictionary called 'ColourOverrides.xaml' in my application project. I then added the 'Colours.xaml' file in the controls library to this as a merged dictionary, and changed all the references in my application project to point to the new ColourOverrides dictionary. Finally, I changed all the colour resources in my custom controls to 'DynamicResource'.

Now I can override a resource key in ColourOverrides and it will be applied across the application. I can also maintain a separate application project with a separate ColourOverrides file but still referencing the same CustomControls library.